# Javascript function not working properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

i do i function with js to change the div color depend on inputs click or select its work perfect on firefox but the radio input not see the onblure property so its never return div to its static color when click any where
here the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function highlight(element) {
        element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#84DFC1';
    }

    function removeHighlight(element) {
        element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
</script>
```

and here the radio inputs

```
<div class="form-item">
<label>Gender:</label>
<input id="male-radio" type="radio" name="radio"value="male" class="radio-form" onselect="highlight(this);" onchange="highlight(this);" onfocus="highlight(this);"  onblur="removeHighlight(this);"></input> 
<label id="male-label">Male</label>
     <input id="female-radio" type="radio" name="radio" class="radio-form" value="female" onselect="highlight(this);" onchange="highlight(this);" onfocus="highlight(this);" onblur="removeHighlight(this);"></input>
         <label class="radioform-label">Female</label> 
    </div>
```

Comment: See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/YmNm9/ - works fine for me in Chrome. (Bearing in mind that Chrome's selection model is still somewhat different to that of Firefox - I think it's intended to be "better", but I just find it a bit of a nuisance - e.g. clicking on a link doesn't change control focus, only tab will do that.)

Answer (score 2):

Safari and Chrome (i.e., WebKit browsers) **do not** fire "focus" and "blur" events in response to mouse actions for radio buttons,  checkboxes, and buttons. [Here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html) is PPK's Quirksmode page on the subject. They **do** fire events when the keyboard is used to navigate around the form, however.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (tested in IE9, FF4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function highlight(element)
    {
        element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#84DFC1';
    }
    function removeHighlight(element)
    {
        element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
</script>

<div class="form-item">
    <label>
        Gender:</label><input id="male-radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="male" class="radio-form" onclick="highlight(this);" onblur="removeHighlight(this);"></input>
    <label id="male-label">
        Male</label>
    <input id="female-radio" type="radio" name="radio" class="radio-form" value="female" onselect="highlight(this);" onclick="highlight(this);" onblur="removeHighlight(this);"></input>
    <label class="radioform-label">
        Female</label>
</div>
```

This will not work in Safari or Chrome. According to the W3C, onblur is not a valid event of the radio button.

You could also just remove the highlight on a timer. See below. This will work in all browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function highlight(element)
        {
            element.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#84DFC1';

            //Remove highlight in 3 seconds
            setTimeout("document.getElementById('" + element.id + "').parentNode.style.backgroundColor = ''", 3000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-item">
        <label>
            Gender:</label><input id="male-radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="male" class="radio-form" onclick="highlight(this);"></input>
        <label id="male-label">
            Male</label>
        <input id="female-radio" type="radio" name="radio" class="radio-form" value="female" onselect="highlight(this);" onclick="highlight(this);"></input>
        <label class="radioform-label">
            Female</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```